Sublayer from a Geopackage file shows as geometrytype 0 (unknown), but it contains points. It doesn't show the points either. How do I fix this?
I have geopackage file that contains sublayers that containts points. I want to access the sublayer and create a new file of it. Despite the points it shows the geometry type as unknown. The points don't show on the map either. How do I fix this? I'm using QGIS with PyQGIS. The geopackage file was created in ArcGIS, if that matters.
Here is an example of the code I have:
path = os.path.join(dir, 'file_path.gpkg|layername=Points')
doors = QgsVectorLayer(path, 'Doors', 'ogr')
crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(crs_nro)
doors.setCrs(crs)
doors.updateExtents()
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(doors)
print(doors.isValid())
node_layers = [doors]

for layer in node_layers:
    geom = QgsWkbTypes.Type(layer.geometryType())
    geom_name = QgsWkbTypes.displayString(geom)
    print(f"Layer Name: {layer.name()}, Valid: {layer.isValid()}, Geometry Type: {geom} ({geom_name})")

It prints:
Layer Name: Doors, Valid: True, Geometry Type: 0 (Unknown)

Yet, when I print some of the contents it's all points. The attribute table for Doors also shows that it is not empty. So how can I get it to show the Geometry Type as containing points? And most importantly how can I get it to show the points from Doors in QGIS on the map?

Geometry columns in GeoPackage layers can be created to hold a specific type of geometry or they can be created with the generic “GEOMETRY” type, in which case they can hold any type of geometry. See Geometry Columns and Geometry Types (Normative).
It maybe be that your GeoPackage layer was created with a generic geometry column, in which case the geometry type of the layer will be reported in QGIS as 0 (Unknown) even if all of the features in that layer are of a uniform geometry type.
Do you know the source of the GeoPackage you created? If you are creating it yourself, you need to be sure to specify a geometry type for the layer, and not just for each feature added to the layer.

Thank you for your reply! :) I do know the source of the geopackage, but I need to ask what type they used. Is the geometry type of the geopackage the same as the one shown in QGIS in Properties > Information > Information from provider > Geometry ?
